# Spring 3.1 Namespace error Component Scan

Tags: java, spring, sax, mule, saxparser

I am using Spring 3.1.1 with mule.
The versions of the jars used inside mule are 3.1.1 RELEASE.

Inside my configuration XML which is a mule flow,

I am getting following SAX parser exception.

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'context:component-scan'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":description, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context":property-placeholder, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":global-property, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":configuration, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":notifications, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-agent, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-security-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-exception-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-flow-construct, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":sub-flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-model, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-interceptor-stack, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-filter, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transformer, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":processor-chain, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":invoke, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-intercepting-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-queue-store, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-processing-strategy}' is expected.
```

My mule flow is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" version="CE-3.3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.comviva.mfs.eig.logging.dataAccess" />

    <jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
```

I made sure that both `xsi:schemaLocation` and  `xmlns:context` are declared.

Cannot figure out why sax parser exception is occurring.

Please Help me out.

**Update:** 
Any Solution to Separate both the XML files will also work for me.
Please help me how to maintain separate ApplicationContext.xml for spring in our mule application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answer for the **Update** part of your question:

You can move `<context:component-scan>` alone to a new context file this way:
appnewcontext.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.comviva.mfs.eig.logging.dataAccess" />
```

and import into the main one:

```
<beans:import resource="appnewcontext.xml"/>
```

Comment: I am getting an exception in the main file.

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "beans" for element "beans:import" is not bound.

all my spring tags are having prefix as <spring:beans>, <spring:property>, etc.

I tried putting <spring:import> inside the <spring:beans>

But my editor is giving me "Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Attribute resource is not defined as a valid property 
  of import"

Comment: After inserting <spring:import> under the <spring:beans>
my editor is saying "Attribute resource is not defined as a valid property of import" 

You have any alternate solution declaring import?

Answer (score 3):

I think you cannot use `<context:component-scan>` as a direct child of `<mule>`. Try the following:

```
<mule ...>
    <spring:beans>
         <context:component-scan ... />
    </spring:beans>
</mule>
```

Comment: Does not work...
Just tried it out..
XML does not take that as a valid statement at all..!

Comment: What if you just type <beans><context:component-scan ... /></beans>?

Comment: @axtavt is correct: this is the right approach assuming the `spring` and `context` namespaces are mapped to their standard Spring schema locations. Note that it is not because whatever XML editor you're complains about the configuration that Mule won't be able to load it...

Comment: hello david, read your answer in mulesoft forum,

I tried importing my spring config file to mule config file,
<spring:import resource="appnedContext.xml"/> inside my <spring:beans>

But editor is not taking it.

Its telling "Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Attribute resource is not defined as a valid property 
  of import
 - Required attribute id is not defined in import
 - Attribute resource is not defined as a valid property 
  of import"

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the resource is not defined error. That is a bug but doesn't impact your application from running.